# How to set the column width in Tabulator's XLS export

Tags: javascript, html, xlsx, tabulator

I am using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) as frontend table framework.
When I download the table data in [Excel file format](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/download#xlsx), my columns have default size. Is it possible to set the width of columns in xls file? I need the columns to be the same size as in the table in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution how to set column widths using sheetjs

```
  table1.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx", {
    documentProcessing: function(workbook) {

      var ws_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      var ws = workbook.Sheets[ws_name];
      
      // setting column with in characters (use wpx for pixels)
      var wscols = [
          {wch:60},
          {wch:7},
          {wch:10},
          {wch:200}
      ];

      ws['!cols'] = wscols;

      return workbook;
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel spreadsheet and Tabulator are not the same thing so if will be difficult to set up a one to one relationship between them. You could set up column widths in your table constructor using these [settings](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/columns#definition). There is also the fit data [options](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/columns#definition).